# Is there a way to identify all rows within the same date with data that only occurs on one row?

Tags: sql-server, database

this one's got me stumped. Am I missing something or do the team need to change the way the data gets dumped into my database?

I'm calculating time spent in "Extended Worktime" but want to exclude all of the users that have been logged in to "Tier 2" on that day.

The issue being that column "Class Name" only populates when users log in and not when they go on "Extended Worktime". My question: is there a query I can script that will identify that Agent is on Tier 2 for that day and exclude that from my report?

If there is a gentle nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated.

| ROWID | Agent_First_Name | Type | AgentID | Exno | Duration | LoginDateTime | BreakReason | Class | ClassName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 61272 | Dave | L | 100 | 3382 | 0 | 17/11/2021 08:00:24 |  | 10 | Tier 1 |
| 61273 | Dave | W | 100 |  | 142 | 17/11/2021 08:07:24 | Extended Worktime | 0 |  |
| 61274 | Dave | W | 100 |  | 112 | 17/11/2021 08:15:24 | Extended Worktime | 0 |  |
| 61275 | John | L | 320 | 4201 | 0 | 17/11/2021 09:04:24 |  | 9 | Tier 2 |
| 61276 | John | W | 320 |  | 100 | 17/11/2021 10:13:24 | Extended Worktime | 0 |  |
| 61277 | John | W | 320 |  | 85 | 17/11/2021 11:15:24 | Extended Worktime | 0 |  |

Comment: A simple `not exists` subquery would work, among other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fill the gaps in `ClassName` this way:

```
with cte 
as
(
  select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AgentID ORDER BY ROWID) rn,
  * from YourTable
)
select 
  ROWID, Agent_First_Name, [Type], BreakReason, 
  case
    when [Type] = 'L' then ClassName
    else lag(ClassName, rn-1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY AgentID ORDER BY ROWID)
    END
from cte
```

This would return:

| ROWID | Agent_First_Name | Type | BreakReason | ClassName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 61272 | Dave | L |  | Tier 1 |
| 61273 | Dave | W | Extended Worktime | Tier 1 |
| 61274 | Dave | W | Extended Worktime | Tier 1 |
| 61275 | John | L |  | Tier 2 |
| 61276 | John | W | Extended Worktime | Tier 2 |
| 61277 | John | W | Extended Worktime | Tier 2 |

Once you got ClassName filled, you can use a `WHERE ClassName != 'Tier 2'` clause or whatever you need:

```
with cte 
as
(
  select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AgentID ORDER BY ROWID) rn,
  * from YourTable
), final
as(
  select 
    ROWID, Agent_First_Name, [Type], BreakReason, 
    case
      when [Type] = 'L' then ClassName
      else lag(ClassName, rn-1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY AgentID ORDER BY ROWID)
    END ClassName
  from cte
)
select * 
from final
where ClassName != 'Tier 2'
```

You have a DBFiddle here to play with it: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=56255540560c74b583af2e9b61df0fd9

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional windowed count for this

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      Tier2 = COUNT(CASE WHEN t.ClassName = 'Tier 2' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY AgentID, CAST(LoginDateTime AS date))
    FROM YourTable t
) t
WHERE t.BreakReason = 'Extended Worktime'
  AND t.Tier2 = 0;
```

Casting to `date` means the count is partitioned by each date

Comment: Thanks mate appreciate it